# ajax post failed but controller & db data ok

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core

im posting data to controller with partailview the controller receive valid data & store it in my DB  but:

1. im getting ajax failed Msg.
2. im not getting a TempData displayed as expected ( i have one for results OK and else for error).
   Im not sure where to put my finger on .

   Index View

   @section Scripts {
   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

   function SubmitREgNews() {
   var data = {
   userName: $("#name").val(),
   UserMail: $("#email").val(),
   TermsOk: $("#bOk").val(),
   };

   ```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/NewsLetter/Create",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            data: data,

            success: function(result) {
                alert('Successfully received Data ');
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Failed to receive the Data');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                console.log('Failed ');
            }
        });
    }
   ```

   Partial view
   @if (@TempData["ErrorMes"] != null)
   {

   @TempData["ErrorMes"]

   }
   @if (@TempData["regOk"] == null)
   {

   ```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form id="studenteForm" novalidate class="needs-validation">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="userName" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="userName" class="form-control" id="name" required />

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="UserMail" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="UserMail" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" />                                                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" id="bOk" asp-for="TermsOk" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TermsOk)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SubmitREgNews();">Add </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    }
   ```

   @section Scripts {
   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
   }
   controller

   ```
          public IActionResult _RegNews()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
     [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("JoinId,userName,UserMail,TermsOk")] JoinNews joinNews )
        {
            var IsNewUser = await _context.joinNewsL.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a =>
                a.UserMail.ToUpper() == (joinNews.UserMail.ToUpper()));

            if ( ModelState.IsValid && IsNewUser==null)
            {
                joinNews.JoinId = Guid.NewGuid();
                joinNews.JoinDate = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Add(joinNews);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                TempData["regOk"] = "You are  register";
                return View("home/index");
                }
            else
            {
                TempData["ErrorMes"] = "You are allready register";
            }
            return PartialView("_RegNews", joinNews);

        }
   ```

Comment: Please format your code it's unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting ajax failed Msg may be that you are returning the wrong path `"home/index"`. Paths in one controller that call a page in another controller should use `"../home/index"`.

Also, Ajax doesn't change page elements. If you want to redirect to another page you can use `Url.Action`.

Like this:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]

public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("JoinId,userName,UserMail,TermsOk")] JoinNews joinNews)
{
    
    var IsNewUser = await _context.joinNewsL.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a =>
        a.UserMail.ToUpper() == (joinNews.UserMail.ToUpper()));

    if (ModelState.IsValid && IsNewUser == null)
    {
        joinNews.JoinId = Guid.NewGuid();
        joinNews.JoinDate = DateTime.Now;
        _context.Add(joinNews);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        TempData["regOk"] = "You are  register";
        return Json(new { redirectUrlOne = Url.Action("Index", "Home")});
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["ErrorMes"] = "You are allready register";
        return Json(new { redirectUrlTwo = Url.Action("_RegNews", "NewsLetter") });
    }
}
```

And your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/NewsLetter/Create",
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        data: data,

        success: function (result) {
              alert('Successfully received Data ');
              if (result.redirectUrlOne !== undefined) {
                    window.location.replace(result.redirectUrlOne);
              } else {
                    window.location.replace(result.redirectUrlTwo);
              }
              console.log(result);
       },
       error: function (error) {
              alert('Failed to receive the Data');
              console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
              console.log('Failed ');
       }
 });
```

If you don't want to use `Url.Action`, you can also do not use Ajax, using the `Form` Tag Helper to submit data is the same. You can check the details in this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Thanks, However its always https://localhost:7077/undefined URL

Comment: in redirectUrlOne its always "localhost:7077/undefined"

Comment: Oh, sorry, this is my mistake, I edited wrong, it should be `if (result.redirectUrlOne !== undefined)`, not `if (result.redirectUrl !== undefined)`.I have changed it in the code, sorry to trouble you. @Assaf Our

Comment: Im still getting undefined

Comment: You can add a variable `var TestUrl = new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") }` before return, and add a breakpoint to see if the path exists.

Comment: If the path exists, you can add a breakpoint in ajax to view the result of the `result` to see if you can receive `redirectUrlOne`. Make sure you have no spelling mistakes. In addition, is your `redirectUrlTwo` also undefined?

Comment: Hi its look like i needed to  >var options = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions(); thanks for your help !